# How to get a parameter into a model from a server response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a module that after you go thru filling it out, it returns a public_token to the user so I get a response like this...

```
/users/transactions?public_token=3982u3doihd9hu2ids9h
```

I need to take that public_token and run it thru a method in the transaction model.

The form that I use to get this token looks like this...

```
<form id= "some-id" method="GET" action="/users/transactions"></form>
```

It "gets" the public_token from the API server but I dont know how to make it submit that token to the transaction model. After it submits that token to the model it would run a method like this to exhange that public_token for an access_token.

```
def token_exchange(options = {})
 exchangeTokenResponse = Api.exchange_token(body: options).parsed_response

  #save the accessToken to initialize a user via Api.set_user
  accessToken = exchnageTokenResponse.access_token
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, the param will be available as part of the params hash, in your case `params[:public_token]`.

When you call the method in your model, pass it as an argument and make sure your model method can accept it as an argument.

```
users_controller.rb

class UserController < ApplicationController

    ...

    def transactions
        @user.token_exchange(params[:public_token])
    end

    ...

end

user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    ...

    def token_exchange(public_token)
        # do stuff
    end

    ...
end
```

Comment: So this public_token is coming from a form in a wicked controller when i try to send it to the transaction controller it goes to the index action. I believe because the form has GET as the method. I still don't see how that gets to the model should I put the method into the index action of the controller?

Comment: You could, but it sounds like you have a routing issue. Do you have a route that goes to the specific method in your controller? Hint: You need one!

Comment: I dont have a route to the specific method. I didn't know I can do that. Do you have an example of how that looks to a specific method?

Comment: You can use a search engine to find what you want easily, but you can start [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: Yeah I thought about that the moment I sent that comment thanks for the help I really appreciate it